# How to Share common postgreSQL(with prisma) database over multiple microservices in NestJS

Tags: postgresql, express, nestjs, microservices, prisma

Hello I am totally new to NestJS and its microservice. A project I am working on should utilize Prisma ORM with PostgreSQL database and NestJS as backend.  Prisma requires prisma.schema and migration files to make changes to the database, that's common knowledge.

But the issue is that, since every microservice has its own NestJS project, it will also have its own prisma.schema file and migration files. For example, I have Project A and Project B. During migration of Project B, all existing schema of Project A will be erased and new schema of Project B will be added. I am a newbie to this microservice thing and don't know what to do. I want to manage a common database across all NestJS projects (microservices). Any help?

Comment: A single PostgreSQL server can contain multiple _databases_. A database can contain multiple _database schemas_. You must use different _database schemas_ or different _databases_ for each project.

Comment: I have multiple database schemas which are used by multiple services, which is why i'm confued.